# Make link of photo in facebook update

Tags: html

I want to show a photo as a status update in facebook and I want people to click the photo which will lead them to a website. So that the photo is the link to a website. This way I don't have to place the photo and link seperately. Is this possible within facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are linking to a website that you have access to - You can do this by setting what are known as "Open Graph" meta tags within the pages on your website that you wish to link to.

The Open Graph meta tags are read by Facebook when you type a URL in to Facebook when writing status updates etc.

Here are an example of how you might want to set up your Open Graph meta tags (within the `<HEAD>` tags within your HTML).

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Your amazing website" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yourwebsite.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourwebsite.com/linked_image.png" />
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This is the description that you want to appear, this will be clickable too!" />
```

You can then use what used to be called the Facebook "Linter", to see how Facebook will "See" any pages that you want to link to from Facebook posts, by typing your URL in the box:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=opengraphprotocol.org

You can also find out more about the Open Graph protocol at [opengraphprotocol.org](http://www.opengraphprotocol.org)